# visual-studio-code: How to open the outline panel collapsed

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there any setting (or extension) to open the outline panel collapsed and keep it collapsed until I click on a item.
Thanks

Comment: Just click on the small arrow to colapse it. It stay collapse til you open it again.

Comment: But there is an arrow, what do you mean? Post pictures

Answer (score 21):

In recent VSCode (version 1.73+), there is an option for this:

```
Settings > outline.collapseItems
```

Select AlwaysCollapse option.

[image]

Comment: They finally did this! Thanks for posting this !

Answer (score 0):

Not possible as of now, but there's an open issue (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/53262) about it. You can send your upvote.
There's also a recent PR about this: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/158650

Additionally, you can use this extension that provides an outline view with an auto collapse option: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Gerrnperl.outline-map&ssr=false#review-details

Comment: The offered extension can't be installed 'ext install Gerrnperl.outline-map' are not found. (vscodium 1.71.0 on arch-linux)

Comment: @GorvGoyl That issue has been closed as completed with the new command `outline.collapseItems` having been added.